# How do I match a date from a list of dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, comparison

I need to compare two dates to see if they are equal from a list of dates in a column.

```
Eg. Sheet 1 Column A
    Date 1
    Date 2
    Date 3
    Date 4
```

Sheet 2 : Row F: Date 5

I want to see if date 5 is equal to any of the dates in column A and return true.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach:

Assume `Date1-Date4` are in `A2:A5`, and `Date5` is in `B2`:

`{=OR(B2=A2:A5)}`

Note that you need to enter the formula as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Even though creating an array formula is not necessary to solve this problem.  At least your solution works. +1.  Btw you can make it pretty by using `<kbd>ctrl</kbd>` and shift and enter